# How many different variable names are there in JAVA? Combinatorics Question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The name of a variable in the JAVA programming language is a string of $1$ to $65,535$ characters, where each character can be an uppercase or a lowercase letter, a dollar sign, an underscore, or a digit. Furthermore, the first character in the string must not be a digit. 
How many different variable names are there in JAVA?

[image: Hint Given:]

I know there are the following characters:

- $26$ Lowercase Letters
- $26$ Uppercase Letters
- $1$ Dollar Sign ($)
   - $1$ Underscore(_)

For a total of $54$ ways.

I am unsure where to go from this point. If this could be worked out with an explanation it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried working out the count of variable names for a couple characters, say, $1,2,3,4,\dots$ characters in length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:  Do you recognize the exponent on $r$ as the number of characters after the first?  How many one character names are there?  What does that represent?

Comment: That makes sense. If the string has only one character, there are 54 possibilities since the first character must not be a digit. If the string has two characters, there are 54 * 64 possibilities and so on. So would the geometric series be 54 * 1 * (64^65535 - 1) / (64 - 1) equaling 54 * (64^65535 - 1) / 63?

Comment: That is correct.